# NPM trouble starting Mongo from script

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, debian

I'm attempting to run a project called Streetmix in Debian 9. I have followed the install instructions to the best of my ability. So, when i use the NPM Start command (with or without sudo) in the streetmix folder I get:

```
> streetmix@1.3.0 prestart /home/dpowell/streetmix/streetmix
> npm run mongo:start


> streetmix@1.3.0 mongo:start /home/dpowell/streetmix/streetmix
> mongod --fork --logpath /dev/null

about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 2076
ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 100
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! streetmix@1.3.0 mongo:start: `mongod --fork --logpath /dev/null`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the streetmix@1.3.0 mongo:start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-15T06_55_52_710Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 100
npm ERR! streetmix@1.3.0 prestart: `npm run mongo:start`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the streetmix@1.3.0 prestart script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-15T06_55_52_721Z-debug.log
```

The instructions at [Streetmix](https://github.com/streetmix/streetmix/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-setup) say that I needed to add the mongodb/bin folder to $PATH, but the command mongo --version works from any folder, which I take it to mean that since mongo is in the usr/bin folder that it's already in my $PATH, correct? (I've also started mongod and then Mongo shell to make sure that's working. I have also created the /data/db folders.

Does anyone have any insight into what my problem may be?

Here are the contents of the log mentioned at the end of the error:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@5.6.0
3 info using node@v8.10.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: streetmix@1.3.0
6 verbose lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: PATH: /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/dpowell/streetmix/streetmix/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
8 verbose lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: CWD: /home/dpowell/streetmix/streetmix
9 silly lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: Args: [ '-c', 'npm run mongo:start' ]
10 silly lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: Returned: code: 100  signal: null
11 info lifecycle streetmix@1.3.0~prestart: Failed to exec prestart script
12 verbose stack Error: streetmix@1.3.0 prestart: `npm run mongo:start`
12 verbose stack Exit status 100
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:285:16)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
12 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:214:7)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
12 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
12 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
12 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
12 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
13 verbose pkgid streetmix@1.3.0
14 verbose cwd /home/dpowell/streetmix/streetmix
15 verbose Linux 4.9.0-6-amd64
16 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "start"
17 verbose node v8.10.0
18 verbose npm  v5.6.0
19 error code ELIFECYCLE
20 error errno 100
21 error streetmix@1.3.0 prestart: `npm run mongo:start`
21 error Exit status 100
22 error Failed at the streetmix@1.3.0 prestart script.
22 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
23 verbose exit [ 100, true ]
```

Comment: Start `mongod --logpath /dev/null` manually to get detailed errors.

Comment: @AlexBlex That's the weird part! Running the terminal from the same path, that command produces no errors!

Comment: So what's the output?

Comment: It gives no output with that command, but if I run the "sudo service mongod status" command afterwards, I get:

mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; disabled; vendor preset: 
   Active: inactive (dead)

Comment: Sorry mate, have you read my first comment? I asked you to execute exact command `mongod --logpath /dev/null` in a terminal. If it gives you no output, you need to re-install mongodb.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case; I tried running that command with no output. I had some trouble installing Mongo 3.4 on Debian 9. I will try and reinstall! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the --fork. I had the same problem.

What you need to do is remove the prestart and mongo:start script from package.json, open mongodb in a seperate terminal. Then you can run npm start as you normally do!

P.S. Make sure you don't commit this modified file

Comment: What an odd error. I wonder if there is a fix or workaround. Thank you for the insight Ayush!

Comment: Indeed, --fork is a linux command used to create a child process and run it in background. I had to modify the scripts when running it on windows. Though there should have been no problem on linux